# Ownage of objects you create

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I know there was discussed a lot of times, but I'm confused in one point in studying memory management.

It says, that you have ownership of objects, you create with alloc/copy/new/mutableCopy or similar methods like allocWithSomething.

But, when you create object like `NSArray *arr = [NSArray array];` in ARC, it is equivalent to write `NSArray *arr = [[NSArray array]autorelease];`

But, i see a lot of times statement like - you own EVERY object you create. But in the case above, we don't actually own object, we just add it to `autorelease pool`. Therefore, we don't have to retain/release it, and it will be vanished as soon as it leave function scope (as Apple says, after an "event").

Can you please clarify that moment for me, do we really OWN EVERY object we create, or only objects with create with alloc/copy/mutableCopy/new, therefore increasing their retain count by +1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question of terminology of ownership in objective-C. The easiest rule would be we are owning the object if the object must be released after we are done with it. So to begin with an owner could be a class, could be a method or a function or even a block and still there are more. The same object may have multiple owners.

The release can be called via `release` method or `autorelease` method. We add it to the autorelease pool to delay its release until the pool is drained which in most cases in the end of the runloop. The code you posted is wrong with the `[[NSArray array]autorelease];` as this would crash your app due to overreleasing. The correct version would be `[[NSArray new] autorelease];` and this is more or less what the static method `array` returns.

So if we exclude the `autorelease` for now we have 3 elements: `retain` will take the ownership of the object and increase the retain count also forcing you to release it at some point; `release` will relinquish the ownership, decreasing the retain count and possibly deallocate the object if retain count drops to zero (the caller was the last owner); Object creation rule says all the methods or functions containing create, alloc, new, copy... will give you the ownership without retaining them and you are responsible to explicitly calling release on them.

When the object is created its retain count is 1. That means that every object on which we call `alloc`+`init` or any version of those will have a retain count of 1 and need to be explicitly released. All other static methods such as `[NSArray array]` are nothing more but convenience to `[[[NSArray alloc] init] autorelease]` and these need to be retained in order to take over the ownership.

So basically if you have a class that has an array pointer `NSArray *_array` and we want to take the ownership we have to write `_array = [someArray retain]` and in `dealloc` method we have to write `[_array release]`. If a method needs to take the ownership we need to call `[someArray retain]` and when we are done with it we need to call `[someArray release]` except when we return the object itself we need to call `return [someArray autorelease]`. These are a very simple rules but some other cases make it extremely hard to track. So what the ARC does is it inserts these calls in the code for you and you do not need to worry about them. Still these same procedures exist as they did before the ARC.

So how exactly ARC inserts these calls is not really explained and differs from the versions. But if we take a look at the example you posted again but let us extend it:

```
- (NSArray *)foo // ARC version
{
    NSArray *arr = [NSArray array];
    for(NSObject *object in arr) NSLog(@"%@", object.description);
    arr = [arr arrayByAddingObject:@"added something"];
    return arr;
}

- (NSArray *)foo // ARC most likely behind the scenes
{
    NSArray *arr = [[NSArray array] retain]; // reatin to claim ownership
    for(NSObject *object in arr) NSLog(@"%@", object.description);
    [arr autorelease]; // need to release it as it will be lost in the next line
    arr = [[arr arrayByAddingObject:@"added something"] retain]; // the arr pointer now points to a different object. Claim the ownership of it
    return [arr autorelease]; // need to relinquish the ownership
}

- (NSArray *)foo // standart non ARC wersion
{
    NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] init]; // we have the ownership by default
    for(NSObject *object in arr) NSLog(@"%@", object.description);
    NSArray *newArray = [[arr arrayByAddingObject:@"added something"] retain]; // need to explicitly retain this one as it is on the autorelease pool
    [arr release]; // We do not need it anymore
    return [newArray autorelease]; // need to relinquish the ownership
}
```

Comment: thank you, very clear answer, now i can see the whole picture :) Still, why many authors taught you that any object you create you own? From what u describe above, i can say, that [NSArray array]; is not object that we own and responsible for it, but rather autoreleased object that we may not care of (if i understand correct pool will drain after each function). Therefore, we only OWN/responsible for objects that are alloc/copy/new/..?

Comment: Yes, rater responsible for those received with any of those key words plus some more but also those we retain. That is important since those are not necessarily created at all. The pool will not drain after every function, very far from that. It will certainly after the runloop but that is way too complicated for this question. Try doing a bit of a research if you are interested...

Comment: well, when then pool will drain? As Apple say, after an "event".

Comment: Imagine you have an endless for loop and an array containing the invocations needed to perform. Each time you use performSelector an invocation was created and added to this array, every timer would add an invocation on this array... Now on every iteration of the loop all touch events or other external button events would be collected and sent to the main window then down to visible view controllers, their's views... Then all its overridden methods would be called and after (or before) them all the array invocations, then drain all the release pools. This is close to what the runloop does....

Comment: in that explanation you abstractly define an application life cycle? If i understand correct, you try to explain, that there is an abstract array that collect "events" and methods to be send, and after it finish launch all that events/methods (application end) it drain pool? Maybe I'm wrong, I guess its hard to explain clearly in few sentences, but i appreciate your help.

Comment: Something like that except that each invocation is most likely to be called the "event" after which the pool is drained. So basically on this level the perform stack is broken down to events where each of them pushes an autorelease pool to the stack and drains it after done. Anyway it is not drained after a method or a function call but rather a system of functions and methods such as the one I described. You may still explicitly push (create) an autorelease pool and drain any time you want. This is very helpful in loops inside the methods which use the autorelease pool.

Answer (score 1):

This may be greatly oversimplified, but when you call [NSArray array], you are not actually requesting the memory space, the NSArray class is doing it for you.  The NSArray class has a method that probably looks like:

```
  + (NSArray *) array
  {
      return [[[NSArray alloc] init] autorelease];
  }
```

So it creates the object and "owns" it, not you.

For what it is worth, rather than "owning", I prefer to think of it as "responsible for".  If you request memory for the object using alloc and similar methods, then you are responsible for releasing that memory.

Answer (score 1):

You own every object that you create - as long as you wish to own it. "Owning" means that you hold a retain count to the object, and that you are going to release that retain count, or pass responsibility and the ownership to someone else.

```
[[NSArray alloc] init...]
```

creates an object that you own at that moment, with a retain count of 1. You may pass that object on to someone else who takes over the ownership.

```
[NSArray array]
```

creates and returns an object, but immediately adds it to an autorelease pool. The object isn't owned by anyone when it is returned; the autorelease pool just keeps it from being deallocated until the autorelease pool itself goes away. Anyone who wishes can take ownership of the object. And of course more than one bit of code can take ownership of the object. The object will go away when everyone releases ownership, and when the autorelease pool also goes away.

Anyway, ARC will take care of all these things for you.